# ITem SharePoint-80 Not Found

Tags: powershell, backup, web-application, item

I just installed SP2010. There's the default web app named SharePoint-80. I am trying to backup this web app using Power Shell.

Here's my command: Backup-SPFarm -Directory C:\Backups -BackupMethod full -Item SharePoint-80 -Verbose

It complains saying "Backup-SPFarm : Item SharePoint-80 not found". Could someone please figure out what my problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double quoting the item name "SharePoint - 80" solved my problem.